# How many right angle triangles are possible in a (m x n) matrix

Tags: swift, matrix, optimization

Let us assume we use a 3x3 matrix of any values inside :

```
|1 2 3|
|4 5 6|
|7 8 9|
```

Triangles I need :

```
1    2  
4 5  5 6

4    5
7 8  8 9

1
4 5
7 8 9
```

Here is the code I tried in swift5:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

let a = [1,2,3]
let b = [4,5,6]
let c = [7,8,9]
let arr = [a,b,c]

let columns = a.count
let rows = arr.count

let minTriangleSize = 2
let maxTriangleSize = min(rows, columns)


func findTheIndex(row: Int, column: Int, triangleSize: Int){
    var str = ""
    for x in 0..<triangleSize{                          
        str += "\n"
        for y in 0...x{                                 
            str += "\(arr[row+x][column+y]) "
        }
    }
    print(str)
}

for size in minTriangleSize...maxTriangleSize{          
    for i in 0...rows-size{                             
        for j in 0...columns-size{                      
            findTheIndex(row: i, column: j, triangleSize: size)
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any optimized way to do this?

Comment: Is this a `python`, `java`, or `swift5` question. Don't tag all.

Comment: I can't put text-formatted triangles in a comment, so use your imagination. Why isn't 2-3-6. a right triangle in your sample matrix? (All 4 possible orientations of triangles, even. So 6-9-8 and 4-1-2 as well.) Does the hypotenuse have to always go from top left to bottom right for some reason?

Comment: @DuncanC Yes, it is supposed to go from top left to bottom right.

Comment: You should edit your question to state the problem clearly.

Answer (score 1):

In your example

```
|1 2 3|
|4 5 6|
|7 8 9|
```

We actually have the following right triangles (if the right angle should just be the left-down one, this isn’t clear from your question) :

```
1      1        2       
4 5    4 5 6    5 6

4      4        5       
7 8    7 8 9    8 9

1      1        2
4      4        5
7 8    7 8 9    8 9
```

So we have 9 triangles.

Python solution:

```
def choose(x: int, k: int):
    # choose(x, 2) = 1 + 2 + ... + (x - 1)
    if k == 0:
        return 1
    return (x * choose(x - 1, k - 1)) // k

def get_solution(n: int, m: int):   
    return choose(n,2) * choose(m,2)
```

Resources: [This](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ProofWithoutWords12N1NChoose2/)